# SSIS Package fails - Unable to retrieve column information from the data source

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2010

I am getting the following messages when writeing data in a dataflow to an updates table, that had been truncated in a previous SSIS step in the same package.

```
Error: 0xC0202009 at DF - Main, OLE DB Dest - Dim Customer Temp [345]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x8007000E.
Error: 0xC020204A at DF - Main, OLE DB Dest - Dim Customer Temp [345]: Unable to retrieve column information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the database is available.
Error: 0xC004701A at DF - Main, SSIS.Pipeline: OLE DB Dest - Dim Customer Temp failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020204A.
```

The table does exist, (I created it a few days ago) the package is running in Visual Studio 2010 against a SQL Server 2012 database. The database is up and running and I can access the table bot before and after running the package. 
The SSIS connection is running under windows authorisation, using my userid/session.

I've been writing SSIS packages since DTS days and have never seen a case where the package could not retrieve meta data, while running, for a table before. Any thoughts.

Note I can go into the OLEDB DB Destination and bring up the columns and prieview the data before running the package in debug mode, where it fails.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I have changed the OLE DB provider and issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem statement**
Using Sql Server Data tool 2015, when package run the following errors appears.

[image]

**Resolution:**
Follow below steps to resolve this problem.

1. Open Sql server management studio.
2. Connect server.
3. Go to Security>>Login.
4. Select user, go to properties by right click on it.

   a. Go to user mapping tab.

   b. Select the destination database and assign db_owner and db_reader. Click OK.

Run package and it will work, hopefully mentioned steps helps you in your scenario as well.